# Get the file path from jcombobox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I am trying to select my file from the jcombobox and display the data in a text area. Currently, I have list out the file name but now once i select the filename from the dropdown its showing me this error:

```
SEVERE: null
```

This is my current code:

```
private void jCmboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //JComboBox jCmbox = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
    String stateName = (String)jCmbox.getSelectedItem();
    updateData(stateName);

}                                      

public void updateData(String path){
    String csvFilename = "";
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(csvFilename);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VisualizationPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    url = VisualizationPanel.class.getResource(path);
    CSVData data = CSVData.loadFromFile(url.toString()); //loads the csv data
    VisualizationPanel visPanel = new VisualizationPanel(this, data); //draws the vis panel and adds the data to it
}
```

I am new to java can someone pls help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Basically you are doing : `new URL("")`

Comment: i am totally dont have idea how to do it actually, i just took some tutorial from the net and edit the code and try it. can you pls help me.

Comment: Try `new URL(path)`  , and provide the full stack trace when you get errors .

Comment: actually, i am trying to modify this code https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/ComboBoxDemo.java

Comment: This is the error i am getting `SEVERE: null
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: SR`

Answer (score 0):

In `updateData()` you are creating a new `URL` from an empty string. This is what is throwing your exception.

You can see that on the first line of `updateData()` you define `csvFilename` to be an empty string. You never reassign a value to that variable so when you come to use it in the `URL` constructor it is still empty.
We can see [from the `URL` constructor spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)) that a the exception you are seeing will be thrown if something is wrong with the spec.
What you *could* do is change the line `String csvFilename = "";` to `String csvFilename = path;`, and see if that fixes your issue.

In fact, though, since you are rewriting your `URL` variable straight after the `try catch` you should just be able to remove that block and avoid the issue completely. Try this:

```
public void updateData(String path){
    String csvFilename = "";
    URL url = VisualizationPanel.class.getResource(path);
    CSVData data = CSVData.loadFromFile(url.toString()); //loads the csv data
    VisualizationPanel visPanel = new VisualizationPanel(this, data); //draws the vis panel and adds the data to it
}
```

Comment: @anonymous5671 Can't help if I don't know where the exception is coming from :)